# Div with dynamic data is not accepting the height in percentage

Tags: html, css

```
<div>
            <table style="width: 100%; height: 97%">
                <tr style="width: 100%;">
                    <td style="height: 20%;" valign="top">                      
                        <div id="divHeaderControls" runat="server" style="height:40%; width:100%;
                            position: relative; background-color: White; border-width: thin;font-weight:bold;">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="height: 50%;" valign="top">
                        <div id="divBody" runat="server" style="border-style: inset; height: 100%;
                            background-color: White; border-width: thin; overflow: scroll; position: relative;
                            top: 0px; left: 0px;">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="width: 100%;">
                    <td style="height: 30;" valign="top">
                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%" BackColor="#BFDBFF">
                            <table style="width: 100%; background-color: White;">
                                <tr>                                    
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Here the divBody will be showing the dynamic data on runtime from the server. I want to set divBody to height in percentage. But when set in percentage it is not showing the contents. It is showing only a strip

Comment: What happens when the data populates the div?

Comment: A table will be inserted inside the div. If I set the div height to percentage it is showing the full table. But when I set the height to any percentage it is showing only a line no table is displayed

Comment: use display command at top div

Comment: Could you setup a plunkr/fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/23zctfpf/ is the link

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the table-layout to be fixed.

```
table{
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Also, be sure to define the fixed pixel height in your parent div or just use 100% in your parent elements. To simply fix, use:

```
html,body{
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Sorry. But I keep this for future visitor that might be helpful.

Comment: I will keep this for future. But i didn't find the exact answer